# Dynamically added script "onload": undefined global callback, which option do I have?

Tags: javascript

**Step 1**: I'm loading an external script, `onload` is set to call `window.initControllers`:

```js
(function(document, tag) {
    var script = document.createElement(tag),
        el = document.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0];
    script.src = 'https://unpkg.com/@hotwired/stimulus@3.1.0/dist/stimulus.umd.js';
    script.onload = function () {
        window.initControllers();
    };

    el.parentNode.insertBefore(script, el);
}(document, 'script'));
```

**Step 2**: actually define the `window.initControllers` function, in another dynamically added script:

```js
(function(document, tag) {
    var script = document.createElement(tag),
        el = document.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0];
    script.type = 'module';
    var contents = "var initControllers = function () { console.log('initControllers'); };";
    contents += 'window.initControllers = initControllers;';

    script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(contents));

    el.parentNode.insertBefore(script, el);
}(document, 'script'));
```

**The problem**: on some page refresh, I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: window.initControllers is not a function.

Apart from adding some fancy methods around `setTimeout`... which option do I have to ensure that `window.initControllers` is defined at the time that script **step 1** is loaded?

Comment: In which order are you executing those two snippets? `script.type = 'module'` means processing of the script content will be deferred. If you are executing them in the order shown, then `insertBefore` will mean they end up in _reverse_ order in the DOM.

Comment: First step 1, then step 2. That is, the http:// import is before the module

Comment: So, the problems seems to be the "module" attribute, but I need it. How to "coordinate" the two scripts?

Comment: You could try and set `defer` for the first one. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer: _"Scripts with the defer attribute will execute in the order in which they appear in the document."_ (But you might still need to change the order in which you are adding those two scripts then, because right now, your second one should get added to the DOM _before_ the first, due to insertBefore.)

Comment: Seems to work fine, would you elaborate an answer?

Answer (score 1):

`script.type = 'module'` means processing of the script content will be deferred - so you could explicitly set `defer` for the first one.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer:

> Scripts with the defer attribute will execute in the order in which they appear in the document.

You might need to change the order that you append them in though, `insertBefore` will mean they end up in reverse order in the DOM.